# Should I add an _id field to a MongoDB sub document

Tags: mongodb

I trying to develop a MongoDB schema for horse race data.  Currently, I have a raceCard document and within the raceCard document there are race sub documents.  So, raceCards are essentially a collection of Races on a particular day at a particular racetrack.

My current schema has a _id for raceCard as follows:  **01Jan14_00BEL** this represents Races at Belmont Park race track on January 1, 2014.

Within the raceCard document there are also 9 race sub documents (arrays) that represent the nine races on the raceCard on January 1, 2014.

Here's my question:

Should the race array include an _id of the form   **01Jan14_01BEL**, where to *01BEL* represents the first race on the Race card **OR**

Should I simply have a raceNumber field that represents the particular race.  **OR**

Should I change my schema and elevate Race to the Document level instead of making it a sub document of RaceCard. Put another way, will making Race a sub document of RaceCard make it more difficult for me to access / query this data.

A popular access pattern will be to query all races that meet a particular set of criteria.  I don't know if making Race a subdocument of raceCard will make this cumbersome.

Comment: Have you mapped out the queries you'll need? That often answers the question you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to do that now.  I'm new to Mongo and I'm getting hung up on what seems to be a pretty fundamental question. Under my proposed schema will I be able to Query raceCard and access ALL races or only races within that raceCard.